# Why can't this scope-like query method use reject?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

According to the Rails [documentation for `scope`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html), a scope such as:

```
class Shirt < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :red, -> { where(color: 'red') }
end
```

is truly:

```
class Shirt < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.red
        where(color: 'red')
    end
end
```

They also say that the relation should act as an `Array`, so doing something like this

```
Shirt.red.each(&block)
```

should work...and it does.

Using everything we know above, why does the following not work?

```
class Shirt < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.short_sleeved
        reject{|object| object.short_sleeved == false}
    end
end
```

`Shirt.red.short_sleeved` results in `undefined method 'reject' for #<Class:0xba552d4>`

Comment: I dont know what you are trying to do? ` class Shirt < ActiveRecord::Base scope :short_sleeve, -> { where(short_sleeve: true) } end ``` will do it

Comment: According to APIDock, the syntax I had was suppose to work...however I found a thread on the rails git repository that had given the same error.  The fix is to prepend all to the enumerator...all.reject{} https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/21943

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define the `short_sleeved` method the way you tried to because ActiveRecord classes aren't ActiveRecord relations.

You defined `short_sleeved` on `Shirt`. `Shirt` is an ActiveRecord model class. It is not itself an ActiveRecord relation. It has methods including `all` and `where` and many others which return ActiveRecord relations.

```
Shirt.class
=> Class
Shirt.respond_to? :each
=> false
Shirt.respond_to? :reject
=> false
```

Like the built-in query methods, scopes return ActiveRecord relations. An ActiveRecord relation has a dynamically generated class. It is not an `Enumerable` but responds to `Enumerable` methods:

```
red_shirts = Shirt.red
red_shirts.class
=> Shirt::ActiveRecord_Relation
red_shirts.respond_to? :each
=> true
red_shirts.respond_to? :reject
=> true
```

So, you could write your method this way:

```
def self.short_sleeved
  all.reject { |object| object.short_sleeved == false }
end
```

However, that loads all the `Shirt`s from the database and then filters them in memory, which is not as efficient for a large number of `Shirt`s as doing the filtering in the database with `where` as MZaragosa suggested. You could do that like this

```
def self.short_sleeved
  where short_sleeved: true
end
```

or

```
scope :short_sleeved, -> { where short_sleeved: true }
```

Comment: I was in the middle of writing this detailed answer while you were writing your to-the-point comment. I'll leave it in case it's helpful to others.

Comment: This thoroughly answers my question.  It is valuable that you brought up this in not efficient, however in my situation, the last scope I needed is not possible with a simple query.  By that point I will have a small enough list that it "should" never be a problem.  Thanks!